Why no "Sign-in with Apple" on Ask Different?
It seems like a no-brainer...espcially since, when you sign up, it offers you to sign in with Google.

Sign-up/in topics are relevant network-wide (on all SE sites). The topic has come up on https://meta.stackexchange.com before and didn't get a lot of traction.

Yes that sounds like a no-brainer, but AD is only one of a whole bunch of (generally non Apple-related) websites that share the same back-end. See that StackExchange icon in the upper left of your screen?
So definitely a no-brainer for any Apple related stuff, but less so for ones specializing in cooking, or Linux or Android, or web development, or coding, or any one of a hundred or so other sites that have little or nothing to do with Apple technologies, specifically.
It has nothing to do with the number of Apple devices out there. What it does have to do with is the number of Apple specific sites in the StackExchange family of websites. I would bet that the traffic generated by just AD is a very small fraction of the total traffic generated across all of the SE sites. Making that decision one based on the percentage of traffic that is specific to AD.
